# flight time is not clear

Tags: air-travel, american-airlines

I've got a flight back to my own country with American Airlines.
And I'm just wondering what the departure time exactly means.
It says `12:45 PM` but when you say `12:45 PM`, it should mean the middle of the night.
Is it really supposed to be a quarter before 1:00 AM??
I'm pretty confused with this AM/PM stuff we don't really use in our mother tongue, thanks.

```
169 American Airlines Wi-Fi on-board    
12:45 PM
LAX
3:55 PM
NRT
Arrives August 3
11h 10m 789 Economy
```

Comment: You've misunderstood the time. 12:45PM is just before one o'clock in the afternoon.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock

Comment: AM is between midnight and noon.  PM is.between noon and midnight.  It's quite simple really.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

12:45 pm is also 12:45 o'clock in international time, i.e. 45 minutes after noon or 15 minutes before 13:00 o'clock.

Your flight leaves at 12:45 LA time. It takes 11 hours and 10 minutes so it arrives in Narita at 23:55 LA time. Japan is 16 hours ahead of LA, so the local time will be 15:55 or 3:55pm in American convention.

Comment: "o'clock" is only used for full hours, without the :00, and using a 12-hour clock. So 12:45, not "12:45 o'clock", and "13:00" (or 1 pm or 1 o'clock in the afternoon, or...), not "13:00 o'clock".

Comment: Terms such as 13:00 o'clock or 12:45 o'clock are not used. The term o'clock is used after a number from one to twelve to say the time when it is exactly that hour: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/o-clock

Comment: what I like about this answer is that it shows a way for others who are unsure about AM and PM to test their hypothesis by using the flight length and landing time.

Answer (score 1):

PM is an acronym for the Latin *post meridiem*, which means 'after noon'. Your flight is scheduled to depart at 45 minutes after midday, i.e. at 12:45 hours.

AM stands for *ante meridiem*, which means 'before noon'.

Comment: This answer is only helpful if you know that the AM and PM start to work the minute after midnight and noon, not just after the next hour. (And if you are not familiar with AM and PM notations it is not that strange a thought.)

Comment: @Willeke The statement "AM and PM start to work the minute after midnight and noon" implies, for example, that PM 'begins' at 12:01 hours. However, this is incorrect as 12:00:01 hours is also 'PM' or after noon. There is a useful discussion on the topic here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28498/precise-names-for-parts-of-a-day/122325#122325